# Best practice to avoid conflicts while code commit on Bitbucket

Tags: github, bitbucket

I have a master branch and from where I have created a branch (named task1-branch), what is the best practice to avoid conflicts when ever I commit code to task1-branch?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the conflict when you merge `task1-branch` back into `master`? Also, while you are working on `task1-branch` are other people working on `master`? I'd recommend making `task1-branch` as short-lived as possible.

Comment: I am getting conflicts whenever I am committing code to task1-branch, as of now I am resolving conflicts manually.

Comment: I assume there are multiple people working on `task1-branch`; otherwise, I don't understand why there are conflicts. Conflicts are a regular occurrence when multiple people are working on the same code. Are you having these conflicts because other people are also committing to `task1-branch`?

Comment: Yes other people will also commit to task1-branch